# C++ Output text file data to char array

Tags: c++, arrays, input, text-files

Simply put I need a program that reads a text file and puts all the data from the text file into and array.

I know you can output/read a text file with

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("numbers.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while (! myfile.eof() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

What I need however is something that can take a text file...

EX:
Answers.txt

```
A
B
C
C
D
B
A
B
```

And outputs the data to an array.

End result should be something like....

```
char answers[] = [A, B, C, C, D, B, A, B];
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Actually I just had a better idea.  std>>cin to a char variable will get you characters, doesn't it?

Comment: Use `std::vector<char>` to store as you read and also in the name of everything that is holy, will people stop using `while(!file.eof())`!!?

Comment: @DeiDei what would you recomend instead?

Comment: @Treycos `while(getline(myfile,line))` is a start.

Comment: @DeiDei I'm using c++ for year... i feel retarded, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the easy way I found out....

```
const int size = 20;
char correctAnswers[size];
ifstream correctAnswersFile;
correctAnswersFile.open("CorrectAnswers.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    correctAnswersFile >> correctAnswers[i];
    cout << correctAnswers[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a vector to add your lines.

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  string line;
  vector<string> lines;
  ifstream myfile ("numbers.txt");

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while (! myfile.eof() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      lines.push_back(line);
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
    cout << lines[i] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If you want more infos on a vector:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector

**Edit:** Okay so if I understand, you need that:

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  string line;
  string file;
  char *str;

  ifstream myfile ("numbers.txt");

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while (! myfile.eof() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      file += line; // Concatenate every lines
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  str = file.c_str(); // str contain the file as an array of char, without the newline char

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is really close to what I need. I just need to use the output to output to an array, but it has to be a char array so it conflicts with string to char

Comment: I feel like there is a much easier way to do this but this works so thank you so much!

Comment: str = file.c_str(); this will be invalid the moment the vector is modified. You need to allocate the string and copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Use `new[]` to get a buffer the same size as the file
2. Then `read` those file contents into that buffer
3. Use the data
4. And don't forget to `delete[]` the buffer.

If you don't want to deal with manual memory allocation and C arrays? Use `getline()` and store it in a `std::string`. No need to `new` or `delete` then, just use `std::string::data()` to get the pointer to the `char` array, if you ever need it.

This smells like a homework question, though.

Comment: *"Use `new[]`"* -- no, bad advice.

Comment: It's part of a homework question. I don't want to have someone do my homework but I'm just stuck in this part hence why I'm asking.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Not necessarily. People get too hung up over this *never use new and delete in modern C++* master-race that it becomes bad.

Comment: @DeiDei There is no reason to use `new` in this case, I am not saying that it is never a good idea to use it but in almost every case it's better to use `std::vector` or smart pointers.

Comment: You're right, there is no reason to use `new[]` because `std::string`s are better. However, his question was to `puts all the data from the text file into and array`. I merely obliged and showed him the C++ way. Still better than `malloc()`...